# Optimum name length of a Java variable from readability perspective

Tags: java, variables, code-readability

Consider the constant in the following Java snippet :

```
public class ConsumerServiceTestFixture {
    private ConsumerServiceTestFixture() {
        throw new AssertionError("This class should not be instantiated");
    }

    public static final String CUSTOMER_ID_NOT_INTEGER = "12345678901";
}
```

The constant **CUSTOMER_ID_NOT_INTEGER** above is used to store a String which cannot be converted into an Integer because it's value is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

This is not apparent from the name of the variable which conveys, at best, that the value is an 'invalid' customer_id. Nothing is conveyed about *why* the value is invalid.

One option would be to write a comment which says something like :

```
// Invalid since this number is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE
public static final String CUSTOMER_ID_NOT_INTEGER = "12345678901";
```

However, if we had to write self-documenting code and not use comments, the only other option would be to make the variable name more descriptive. Something like :

```
public static final String CUSTOMER_ID_GREATER_THAN_INTEGER_MAX_VALUE = "12345678901";
```

But, with the above option I am not happy about the length of the variable name, specially if you consider the following snippet about optimal variable name length from Code Complete 2 :

[image: Chapter 11. The Power of Variable Names]

How would you suggest I balance the length of the variable name vs. code readability ?

Comment: Does the value of the constant really matter (larger than MAX_INT)? Why not simply `INVALID_CUSTOMER_ID`?

Comment: @assylias, the value of that constant is used in a test which tests the behavior of the related piece of code, when a String-which-is-an-invalid-integer is passed to it. Thus it must be greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: So why not "MAX_CUSTOMER_ID"?  Bottom line: if you need more than two or three words, then you're not defining it clearly enough.  IMHO...  PS: I think "i" and "x1/x2" are *ideal* for many local variables.  Never underestimate 1) the importance of 1) brevity, or 2) the usefulness of idiom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If instead of a // comment you use a /** comment (that is, javadoc), when a programmer uses your constant from an IDE or looks at your javadoc, he will get a full explanations of all the pros and cons of such a design, why it was done this way etc..

Unfortunately, you cannot name it "CUSTOMER_ID_THAT_IS_A_STRING_BECAUSE_IF_IT_WAS_AN_INT_IT_WOULD_BE_TOO_LARGE".